# Запретить регистрацию в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Делаю проверку на регистрации с одного ip адреса в контроллере, и не знаю как правильно вывести пользователю ошибку об этом с редиректом на страницу регистрации. Код ниже из файла Auth/RegisterController.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно после того, как пользователь первый раз зарегался, нужно его ip записать в базу и перед каждой регистрацией любого пользователя, сначала сделать массив всех ip из базы и сравнивать

Comment: @DivMan нет, эта часть уже готова, у меня вопрос заключается в том, как вернуть пользователя назад, на страницу регистрации и вывести какое то уведомление. Сложность заключается сделать это из стандартного контроллера RegisterController на ларавел

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта:

```
abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
```

Или

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Ваш IP в черном списке');
```

Все зависит от того, что именно Вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: В итоге хочу получить второй вариант, но получаю ошибку `Method [save] does not exist on Redirect.`

Comment: Если по трейсу посмотреть, где выполняется метод `save()`?